# Why chemists are interested in character tables?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

I'm a french PhD student and I'm working on representation theory (of non-compact Lie groups).

By the way I try to give a "concrete" sense to character tables of finite groups and I have a lot of question about that (e.g. what are the geometric interpretations? can it help to compute a measure on a group? etc).
I know that chemists study a lot character tables and I guess it could give me good idea to understand why. Does someone know this kind of stuffs?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Group_Theory/Group_Theory%3A_Theory

Comment: The finite subgroups of SO(3) make sense for symmetry of a molecule. The nuclei are in some arrangement. Why to linearize into representations? That is because the action on the molecule gives an action on wavefunctions.